# Does having more threads than partitions cause harm?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am working on an application where the concurrency in the Listener container has been set to 8 when there is only a single partition. I know this will result in 7 idle threads and should be modified to either decrease the concurrency or increase the partitions.

However, I am wondering if this can cause any other adverse impacts? We are seeing a lot of rebalances under heavy load but haven’t been able to get to the root cause.

There is high memory and CPU on the machine and wondering if these idle threads could cause spikes to those and impact heartbeat request responses?

Comment: It must not result in 7 idle threads, actually. Check here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#using-ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer, search for this sentence: "If the concurrency is greater than the number of TopicPartitions, the concurrency is adjusted down such that each container gets one partition". Same confirms the source code of the ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/156d09662a7acda86d89fe4250abbf15a13d0179/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.java#L216

Comment: Also, what value do you have for "max.poll.records" in your consumer? It can happen that you process too many messages in a batch at once. Does the problem still exist if you lower this value?

Comment: `...adjusted down...` only applies to manually assigned partitions; when using group management you will end up with idle containers. It's best to fix that, but I would be surprised if those idle containers were the cause of your issues; you may need to profile your app to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Max poll records is 200k and max poll interval is 1 hour. We are completing the processing within that timeframe. However cpu is spiking on the machine quite a bit and there is a good deal of traffic happening on these services. My feeling is it may be related to our session timeout, but the issue is intermittent and seems hard to prove.